# How to make spray-can client follow redirects

Tags: http, scala, redirect, akka, spray

When requesting some pages with the following code:

```
HttpDialog(httpClient, IDN.toASCII(domain)).send(HttpRequest(uri = "/")).end
```

spray-can client returns responses with redirects to another URLs (e.g. 302 Found). Is there a standard way of telling spray to automatically follow redirects? And if not, what is the best way to implement this behavior myself with akka futures?

Comment: It looks like there's an issue open to implement [redirect following](https://github.com/spray/spray/issues/132), so I guess it doesn't support it presently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 2:** The PR was merged and documentation for redirection following is spray-can can now be found [here](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.2/spray-can/http-client/#redirection-following)

**Update:** I decided to have a crack at implementing this and have [sent a PR](https://github.com/spray/spray/pull/560). Hopefully it will get merged.

---

There is no way to currently tell spray-can client to follow `3xx` redirects. See [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spray-user/VSqrUiTqtDg) for more details.

There is an [open ticket](https://github.com/spray/spray/issues/132), so hopefully this will happen in the future. I'm sure a contribution would be welcomed.

Comment: Update: the above referenced PR was merged.  Documentation on redirects in spray-client can be found here:  http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.2/spray-can/http-client/#redirection-following